# How to guess unknown dateTime format?

Tags: java, date

I have a DateTime which I received as JSON via a REST Servce of the Couchbase's Sync Gateway:

"2015-05-20T13:32:25.9999478-07:00"

I do not have the access to the Sync Gateway's configs. 
I did no find any documentation about the default format of Sync Gateway's dateTime format.

I do not understand what the **.9999478-07:00"** means. 
Is there a way to guess that somehow?

Comment: Wouldnt checking the DB documentation for DateTime (it's format, description, etc) be able to elaborate on what that means?

Comment: TIMESTAMP - format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS

Comment: try formatting your date before doing an insert

Comment: Why do you read dates as strings in the first place? Why not read them as a Timestamp instead. You wouldn't have to guess anything. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp%28int%29

Comment: I would echo @ryekayo in that you should read the DB documentation to be absolutely sure, but would find it very likely that .99... is fractions of a second and the -7:00 refers to which timezone the time is given, which in this case would be [pacific time.](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/map/)

Comment: Unfortunately this DateTime is delivered via a REST API by the CouchBase's Sync Gateway. This Date - is the expiration Date of the user account, I don't thinkI can modify it's format since its system data. GC123UNC thnx, your answer helped me alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the ISO standard notation for date time

```
YYYY-MM-DD,
then a 'T' for time, HH:MI:SS.S* (fractional seconds),
+/- time zone (there are half our zones!)
```

Time and also time zone optional.
Look in the wikipedia or javadoc.
When no time zone the date time representation can be sorted alphabetical to be naturally ordered.